# AngularJS, UI Bootsrap, MVC Frontend - data-ng-click is not working

Tags: java, javascript, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to register user (take some information from form input at frontend and send it to backend via AngularJS) but I am experiencing some problems.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="collectionsApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Collections</title>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/service/userService.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controller/indexController.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controller/registerController.js"></script>
</html>
```

As you ca see, I have included Bootstrap UI, AngularJS, Bootstarp CSS and my project files: userService.js, indexController.js and registerController.js. I have created atributes data-ng-app="collectionsApp" (created in app.js) and data-ng-view (routing works just fine).

Here is my app.js file:

```
var collectionsApp = angular.module('collectionsApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

collectionsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
                   templateUrl : '/view/login.html',
                   controller : 'loginController'
    })
                  .when('/register', {
                   templateUrl : '/view/register.html',
                   controller : 'registerController'
    }).

    otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/login'
    });
});
```

As you can see I have included my registerControll and loginControll in app.js so i do not have to do it in register.html and login.html.

Here is my register.html file:

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-signin" role="form">
      <h1 class="form-signin-heading">Please register</h1>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required data-ng-model='user.email'> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required data-ng-model='user.password'>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firts name" required data-ng-model='user.firstName'>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required data-ng-model='user.LastName'>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" data-ng-click="register(user)">Register</button>
      <div>
         <a href="#login">Login</a>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

On data-ng-click register(user) function is called from userControl.js file.
Here is my userController.js file:

```
collectionsApp.controller('registerController', function($scope, userService) {
    userService.register($scope.user).then(function(data){

    });
});
```

From this file, function from userService.js file is called.
Here is my userService.js file:

```
collectionsApp.service('userService', function($scope, $http) {
    return {
        login : function(user) {
            $http.post('/user/login', user).then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        },
        register : function(user) {
            $http.post('/user/add', user).then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

From here register function targets /user/add in userController.java in backend. Here is that file:

```
package x.y.collections.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import x.y.collections.dao.UserDAO;
import x.y.collections.model.User;
import x.y.collections.utility.Response;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Resource
    UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping("/find/{id}")
    public User FindUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userDao.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<String, String> AddUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        final User requestedUserBody = userDao.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (requestedUserBody.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) {
            return Response.setError("User allready in databse!");
        } else {
            userDao.save(user);
            return Response.setSuccess("Registration succsessful!");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<String, String> LoginUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        final User requestedUserBody = userDao.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (requestedUserBody.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            return Response.setError("Username and password do not match!");
        } else {
            return Response.setSuccess("Login succsessful!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I start server and go to my frontend via Chrome and localhost:port in adressbar I can see that routing is working, but when I fill in the form, and press button that is supposed to trigger data-ng-click="register(user)" noting happens. When I go right click > inspect element > console : I see this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=<div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20userService
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:36:202
    at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:36:270
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:6)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:165)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:435)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:36)
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
Than you in advance...
Papi

Answer (score 0):

In your registerController

```
collectionsApp.controller('registerController', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.user = {};
    .....
    $scope.register = function(){
         userService.register($scope.user).then(function(data){

         });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, but it still does not work... Same old error at js console and I cant see any entry in database, table are empty...